# Hibernate SessionFactory - correct way to create factory, session and handle resources

Tags: java, hibernate, exception, sessionfactory

For teaching purposes, I am creating Hibernate console applications. Since Hibernate is quite complex, I want to be sure that I handle the initialization, exceptions, and shutdown correctly. The examples that I have found are not optimal in my opinion. (Official Hibernate examples use test cases.)

I have `HibernateUtil` for initialization and shutdown of Hibernate.

```
package com.zetcode.util;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.boot.MetadataSources;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistry;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder;

public class HibernateUtil {

    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public HibernateUtil() {

        createSessionFactory();
    }

    private void createSessionFactory() {

        StandardServiceRegistry registry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
                .configure() // configures settings from hibernate.cfg.xml
                .build();
        sessionFactory = new MetadataSources(registry).buildMetadata().buildSessionFactory();

 //       try {

   //         sessionFactory = new MetadataSources(registry).buildMetadata().buildSessionFactory();
    //    } catch (Exception e) {
            // The registry would be destroyed by the SessionFactory, //but we had trouble building the SessionFactory
            // so destroy it manually.
          //  StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.destroy(registry);
        }
    }

    public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {

  //      if (sessionFactory == null) {

       //     createSessionFactory();
     //   }

        return sessionFactory;
    }

    public void shutdown() {

        getSessionFactory().close();
    }
}
```

Here is a console Java application:

```
package com.zetcode.main;

import com.zetcode.bean.Continent;
import com.zetcode.bean.Country;
import com.zetcode.util.HibernateUtil;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;
import javax.persistence.Query;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;

public class Application {    

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        HibernateUtil hutil = new HibernateUtil();
        SessionFactory sessionFactory = hutil.getSessionFactory();

        try (Session session = sessionFactory.openSession()) {

            session.beginTransaction();

            Continent europe = new Continent("Europe");
            Continent asia = new Continent("Asia");

            Country svk = new Country("Slovakia");
            Country hun = new Country("Hungary");

            Set<Country> europeCountries = new HashSet<>();
            europeCountries.add(svk);
            europeCountries.add(hun);
            europe.setCountries(europeCountries);

            Country chi = new Country("China");
            Country afg = new Country("Afganistan");

            Set<Country> asiaCountries = new HashSet<>();

            asiaCountries.add(chi);
            asiaCountries.add(afg);
            asia.setCountries(asiaCountries);

            session.save(europe);
            session.save(asia);

            // moved 
            //session.getTransaction().commit();

            Query query = session.createQuery("SELECT c FROM Country c");
            List<Country> countries = query.getResultList();

            countries.stream().forEach((x) -> System.out.println(x));

            Query query2 = session.createQuery("SELECT c FROM Continent c");
            List<Continent> continents = query2.getResultList();

            continents.stream().forEach((x) -> System.out.println(x));

            session.getTransaction().commit();
        } finally {

            hutil.shutdown();
        }
    }
}
```

The example works OK. But, is this code correct? I am using Hibernate 5.2.

**Edit** I have incorporated the suggestions from the comments into the code.

Comment: You begin a transaction, but commit it before you have finished using your entities and the session. You create the sessionFactory in the cnstructor, but still keeps checking for null in in getSessionFactory() (which is not thread-safe, but it's not a big deal in your app).

Comment: There is a commit: `session.getTransaction().commit();`

Comment: So in order to improve my code example, I should place `session.getTransaction().commit();` at the end of the try block and remove the null checking in `getSessionFactory`?

Comment: Yes. Or restart a new transaction is you want to have two of them. You should also remove the catch block in the createSessionFactory method (or at least rethrow a runtime exception from it). In its current state, if an exception is thrown, it will be caught, and getSessionFactory() will return null, without giving any clue about what the problem is.

Comment: This should be posted on codereview.stackexchange.com, BTW.

Comment: I have modified the code example according to the suggestions. I hope now it is OK.